# transformar string em array javascript

Tags: javascript, json, array

Boa tarde,

tenho a seguinte string

```
[{"programa":"teste"},{"programa":"Aprender"},{"programa":"outro teste","indice":"0;1;0"}][{"programa":"Programando 1","indice":"1;2;3"},{"programa":"hostórico","indice":"1;2;2"},{"programa":"análise","indice":"1;2;1"}]
```

como faço para obter array através dessa string?

Comment: Era pra ter 2 arrays nesse JSON ? `...{"programa":"outro teste","indice":"0;1;0"}][{"programa":"Programando 1","indice":"1;2;3"},...`

Comment: na verdade usei o concat para unir

Comment: Essa string vem de onde ? O formato era suposto ser JSON ?

Comment: sim, seria mas como ela é a junção acabou ficando com esse formato. mas irei ajustar a formatação. OBg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sua string `JSON` parece estar mal formatada, tem dois arrays mal definidos (isso dá erro: `][`).

Fiz uma pequena alteração para que seja um array válido e converti para objeto usando `JSON.parse`:

```js
var x = '{"1":[{"programa":"teste"},{"programa":"Aprender"},{"programa":"outro teste","indice":"0;1;0"}],"2":[{"programa":"Programando 1","indice":"1;2;3"},{"programa":"hostórico","indice":"1;2;2"},{"programa":"análise","indice":"1;2;1"}]}';

var o = JSON.parse(x);
console.log(o);
```

Comment: Se você utilizar `eval` ao invés de `JSON.parse`, daí o javascript da pergunta é válido! Mas o resultado é `undefined`.

Comment: Nem tinha pensado nisso, pensei num array com array dentro. Testei aqui e realmente fica `undefined` bem observado